# How do I make a YARA signature that does NOT look in the resource section?

Tags: malware, yara

I'm trying to use YARA to sort out a variety of files into families. Some malware drops other malware from images within their resource images. What I'd like to do is write a signature that ignores string hits that exist within the resource section. This would allow my signatures to correctly identify droppers from the malware that is dropped. I tried doing something like this:

```
        (pe.sections[0].characteristics & pe.SECTION_CNT_CODE) and $handshake
```

to limit my condition to the .text section, but this is definitely not write. That is going to trigger only if the .text section is the first section and the $handshake string exists anywhere within the binary. what I'd like is a way to limit the $handshake to the .text section (or in any section that is not the resource section).

Is this even possible with YARA or is that getting a bit too complicated for YARA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WXS on the Yara Google Groups was kind enough to post an answer to this question. He has several examples here: https://gist.github.com/wxsBSD/4d5d7677578f80cdf82a